# Paralysis, what are the best items to protect against it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, optimization, equipment

Looking for items in the 15k and under range to protect from paralysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This player and DM [also](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114972/8610) recommends and fully supports [Ernir](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/5901/ernir?tab=profile)'s [Lists of Necessary Magic Items](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items) (hosted on the *Giant in the Playground* forums), a fantastic resource for improving any character's chances of survival. This DM's monsters frequently rely on the Lists' suggestion of the face slot item ***third eye freedom*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 141) (2,600 gp; 0 lbs.) that allows the wearer 1/day to take an immediate *mental* action (so the *eye* can be used while paralyzed) to gain for 1 round an effect like the spell [*freedom of movement*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#freedom-of-movement), which specifically overcomes paralysis.<sup>1</sup>

Dumpster-diving yields a few additional possibilities unmentioned by the Lists, most preventative rather than curative and often requiring DM adjudication or approval.

- An ***eternal wand*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 159–60) (460+ gp; 0 lbs.) is odd in that, while it has *wand* in its name, whether or not it's *technically* a wand or, in fact, a wondrous item is unclear, it, for example, having as prerequisites for its creation *both* the feat Craft Wand *and* the feat Craft Wondrous Item (*Player's Handbook* 92 and 92–3, respectively). This means the DM may or may not rule that an *eternal wand* can, for example, be put in a wand chamber (*Dungeonscape* 30, 34) (100 gp; 0 lbs.) and may or may not allow a user to make a Use Magic Device skill check to activate a wand (DC 20) to activate an *eternal wand*. In addition to these factors, an *eternal wand* is also activated *via* command word… so, for example, it's useless to the owner *after* the owner's paralyzed. This makes the spells below preventative, needing to be employed *prior* to an engagement with foes that can cause paralysis. Anyway, an *eternal wand* can be created to hold the following spells that defend against paralysis:

  - The 2nd-level Sor-spell ***essence of the dragon*** [trans] (*Races of the Dragon* 112–13) for 1 min./level grants a touched subject the type [dragon](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#dragon). The subject's new type grants it, among other traits possessed by the type dragon, immunity to paralysis. An *eternal wand of essence of the dragon* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) has a price of 4,420 gp. (An identical yet non-*eternal* wand is 4,500 gp.)
  - The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***heart of water*** [trans] (*Complete Mage* 107) for 1 hour/level grants the caster bonuses about which he probably doesn't care. However, once during the spell's duration, the caster can take a swift action (that's *probably* mental but first confirm with the DM!) to end the spell's other effects and activate for 1 round/level an effect like the spell *freedom of movement*. An *eternal wand of heart of water* (3rd-level spell at caster level 5) has a price of 10,900 gp. (An identical yet non-*eternal* wand is 11,250 gp.)
- A [**ready-drink helm**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59272/8610) (or, reskinned for steampunk, a [**dwarven injector**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/58129/8610)) (*Dragon* #294 80-1) (150 gp; 2 lbs.) holds multiple potions, each of which can be consumed by the wearer as a free action. A (some would argue) *unbalanced* mundane item with game-changing implications, a DM that allows either item into the campaign probably shouldn't also allow the other. This is an alternative to the *eternal wand* for noncasters or those with low Use Magic Device skill modifiers. Also like the *eternal wand*, this is limited to *preventing*—rather than *removing*—paralysis.

  In short, load up the fantasy beer hat with a *potion of essence of the dragon* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (300 gp; 0.1 lbs.), go first, take a free action (that's *definitely* not mental!) to chug the *potion*, and worry not about paralysis for the remainder of the encounter.<sup>2</sup>
- A ***spellworm*** (*Dragon* #343 80) (cost as per potion; 0 lbs.) allows the user to take *either* a full-round action *or* a standard action (the text is contradictory) to use as a spell-like ability (at the creator's caster level but the user's ability modifier) the contained spell effect—which can be a spell of *any* level. Although a 1-use item (like a potion), as a spell-like ability, a *spellworm* is typically more versatile than a potion. (Even so, a *spellworm* still can't be used while paralyzed!) As a *spellworm* is *an actual magical worm living inside your body*, it's challenging to steal (take that, Sleight of Hand skill!) and difficult to destroy. (You've more pressing problems than paralysis if there's line of effect *to your innards!*)

  A *spellworm* is unusually hard to create, requiring the feat Craft Wondrous Item and *either* the subtype wormspawn (described in the article) *or* the additional and apocryphal feat Wormbound Spellcaster, but the extraordinary ability item creation of a level 3 artificer can likely bypass the subtype prerequisite with a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the race of a creature possessing the subtype.

  This is another alternative to the *eternal wand* for noncasters or those with low Use Magic Device skill modifiers, except likely even harder to get approved than the fantasy beer hat, above. *And*, like some other options here, a *spellworm of essence of the dragon*, for example, doesn't do *you* any good *after* you're paralyzed. So, instead,—because it's dangerous to go alone,—plan ahead so folks can help each other out and have everyone get at least one *spellworm* of one (or *all!*) of these spells:

  - The 2nd-level Clr spell [***remove paralysis***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#remove-paralysis) [abjur] (*PH* 271) targets a subject within close range, ending any ongoing paralysis effects on the subject. A *spellworm of remove paralysis* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) has a price of 300 gp.
  - The 4th-level Clr spell ***freedom of movement*** [abjur] (*PH* 233) can be used either on oneself or another touched creature. Valuable here for obvious reasons. A *spellworm of freedom of movement* (4th-level spell at caster level 7) has a price of 1,400 gp.
  - The 4th-level Clr spell ***panacea*** [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 152–3) allows the caster to touch a creature and remove, among other wide-ranging conditions, a creature's paralysis. A *spellworm of panacea* (4th-level spell at caster level 7) has a price of 1,400 gp.
- The torso slot item ***vestments of ebonsilk*** (*MIC* 147) (5,000 gp; 1 lb.)—if the wearer can succeed on a [Use Magic Device](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device) skill check to emulate the level 1 [cleric](http://dndsrd.net/cleric.html#cleric) class feature deity, domains, and domain spells (DC 21) and picks Lolth as the wearer's virtual deity *and* if the wearer can succeed on a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the class feature spells of a level 13 cleric (DC 33) so the wearer can virtually sacrifice a spell that he doesn't have to activate the *vestments* (like the example has Lidda sacrificing a turn undead attempt she doesn't have to activate the magic chalice (*PH* 86))—grants the wearer for 1 hour, among other benefits, an effect like the spell *freedom of movement*. The wearer 1 hour later must repeat these skill checks to continue to reap the *vestments*' benefits.

  Controversial because *it just seems wrong*—even to this liberal DM—to be able to deceive magic items like this, being able to make such a high Use Magic Device skill check consistently usually comes pretty late in the game anyway. But once the wearer *can* make such checks *and* if the wearer's allowed by the DM to make such checks against the *vestments*, the wearer saves at least 35,000 gp and gets extra benefits besides (cf. the [*cloak of arachnida*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#cloak-of-arachnida) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 252) (14,000 gp; 1 lb.), the [*ring of freedom of movement*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-freedom-of-movement) (*DMG* 232) (40,000 gp; 0 lbs.)).

Honorable mention goes to the ***novice Iron Heart vest*** (*Tome of Battle* 149–50) (1,500 gp; 1 lb.) that is, if allowed, combined with a second *novice Iron Heart vest* into a lone item with a total price of 3,750 gp. When combined, the wearer should be able to pick two Iron Heart maneuvers for which he meets the prerequisites, like, for example, the 2nd-level Iron Heart maneuver disarming strike [strike] (*ToB* 67) then the 3rd-level Iron Heart maneuver Iron Heart surge [special] (*ToB* 68). The maneuver Iron Heart surge *technically* can't end a paralysis effect (a creature "must be able to move" (38) to initiate a martial maneuver), but—[by Crom!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/70255/8610)—it totally *should!*

---

<sup>**1**</sup> As an aside, this DM often finds himself combining the *third eye freedom* with the *raptor's mask* (*MIC* 210) (3,500 gp; 0 lbs.), adding 3,900 gp to the price of the *mask*. Seriously, if you're worried about paralysis, you're also probably worried about blindness, and the *mask* means not having to take actions to use an effect like the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *vision of the omniscient eye* [div] (*Dragon Magic* 74) or whatever. Just a friendly heads-up.
<sup>**2**</sup> The DM may allow *Gremma's cauldron* (*Expedition to Undermountain* 217) (5,000 gp; 5 lbs.), in addition to its other effects, to, for example, transform a *scroll of heart of water* (3rd-level spell at caster level 5) (375 gp; 0 lbs.) into a *potion of heart of water* (3rd-level spell at caster level 5) (750 gp; 0.1 lbs.) by having the brewer expend [raw materials](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103880/8610) and XP to make up the price difference between the *scroll* and *potion* (i.e. 375 gp and 15 XP). Thus the *cauldron* may allow the creation of potions of spells that have a range of personal (e.g. [*divine favor*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#divine-favor), [*shield*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shield)) *and*, not inconsequentially, that have spell levels higher than 3rd (e.g. [*divine power*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#divine-power), *freedom of movement*, [*righteous might*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#righteous-might)), both [normally impossible](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-potions).

Comment: Awesome answer. minor quibble, though: there are other arguable ways to get normally-personal and/or normally-greater-than-3rd-level spells into potions, which your footnote seems to suggest is only possible with the *cauldron*. A spellguard of Silverymoon/master alchemist, for example, may well be able to do it.

Comment: @KRyan I don't doubt there are more ways to somehow get high-level personal-range potions, but the *cauldron*'s the most generally useful; I can soften that stance further if you want. (And I don't think being able to "cast any personal-range defensive arcane spell on another character with a touch" would be transferable into a potion. Is there something about the spellguard or master alchemist I'm missing?)

Comment: Yeah, the “except perhaps with a *cauldron*” implies a stronger statement to me than the one you seem to intend. As for spellguard of Silverymoon, you are correct that it’s a stretch, but I think there is room enough there to get into a semantic argument about whether the limitation on potions refers to the spell’s default state or the spell as you cast it. After all, a spellguard of Silverymoon can target one or more creatures with his otherwise-personal spells.

Comment: @KRyan Meh. I'll ditch the phrase. No worries. But, since we're on the topic, like all magic items that have spells as prerequisites for their creation, "The act of brewing [a potion] triggers the prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting until the character has rested and regained spells." I'd look seriously askance at a player who claimed that *triggered* there means *cast* so as to employ his PC's class features when creating a magic item! That sounds like an *extremely* dangerous precedent (cf. incantatrix, dweomerkeeper, etc.)

Comment: Oh yes, definitely not a great choice of precedent.

Comment: @KRyan O, and—because I didn't in the first comment—thank you, and, again, on an unrelated note, *thank you*, that second for originally pointing me at Ernir's Lists. While I've mentally expanded it to include other stuff I've discovered over the years, it's a continual touchstone for me, informing how I play this game; it's made me a better player and DM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72834/discussion-between-kryan-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Answer (score 9):

Your best resource for this kind of thing will always be [Ernir’s Lists of Necessary Magic Items](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?187851-3-5-Lists-of-Necessary-Magic-Items), the author of which goes by @Ernir around here.

One of the lists he mentions is for *freedom of movement*, because

> **Why you need it:** Because of Solid Fog, because you can be insta-killed if you are paralyzed, and because monsters have ginormous grapple checks.

The three entries in the “cheap” section meet your price limit:

> - *Third Eye Freedom* (MIC). 2600GP, face slot. Once per day, as an immediate action, gain Freedom of Movement for one round. Excellent panic button.
> - *Periapt of the Sullen Sea* (MIC). 6000GP, throat slot. Allows you to spend a 4th level spell slot to cast Freedom of Movement. Useless if you don't have 4th level spell slots to spread around, but a nice backup otherwise.
> - *Vest of Free Movement* (MIC). 12000GP, torso slot. Freedom of Movement for 3 rounds, three times per day. What is good about the activation is that it's a swift action, what's bad is that it's a command activation, which means it won't work if you have already been paralyzed.

Note (as mentioned in the **Why you need it** section), *freedom of movement* protects against a whole lot more than just paralysis.

Comment: @Ernir If you happen to stop by and see this, I would be happy to delete this in favor of your own answer. After all, I’m just reporting your work—you deserve the rep far more than I.